# How to add multiple namespace declaration in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, transformation

I am facing an issue while transforming an input xml to oputput xml through xslt 2.0. Following is the input xml

```
<Heard sequence_id="10363284">
   <doctype>News</doctype>
   <Banner>--Alert--</Banner>
   <PCategory>WW</PCategory>
   <Topic>XX,YY,ZZ</Topic>
   <type>RealTime</type>
   <headline>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</headline>
   <TextBody>xxxxxxxxx</TextBody>
   <headline_datetime>2014-09-09T10:51:27-04:00</headline_datetime>
   <service_line>ABC</service_line>
   <page_num>123</page_num>
</Heard>
```

The output expected should be

```
<mgh:message xsi:schemaLocation="http://comp.com/prismPlus-XSD HeardsContent.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1" xmlns:prl="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/prl/2.0" xmlns:mgh="http://comp.com/prismPlus-XSD">           
    <mgh:article>       
        <mgh:head>
            <dc:identifier>10363284</dc:identifier>
            <dc:title>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</dc:title>
            <dc:publisher>Comp</dc:publisher>
            <dc:subject>--Alert--</dc:subject>
            <prism:publicationDate>09/08/2014</prism:publicationDate>
            <prism:subsection1>News</prism:subsection1>
            <prism:keyword>XX,YY,ZZ</prism:keyword>
            <mgh:category>WW</mgh:category>
            <mgh:serviceLine>ABC</mgh:serviceLine>
            <mgh:pageNumber>123</mgh:pageNumber>
        </mgh:head>
        <mgh:contentFeatureBody>
            <body>
                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            </body>
        </mgh:newsFeatureBody>                  
    </mgh:article>    
</mgh:message>
```

In the xslt 2.0, how do I add multiple namespaces like **dc, prism, mgh**? Please let me know if you need additional information as I am fairly new to SO and would highly appreciate if you can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating the `mgh:message` as a literal result element then provided those namespace declarations are in scope at the appropriate place it should just work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.0"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1"
    xmlns:prl="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/prl/2.0"
    xmlns:mgh="http://comp.com/prismPlus-XSD">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <mgh:message xsi:schemaLocation="http://comp.com/prismPlus-XSD HeardsContent.xsd">
      <!-- etc -->
```

since literal result elements preserve the namespaces that are in scope at that point in the stylesheet.

You could of course just put the declarations on the `mgh:message` element itself rather than on the `xsl:stylesheet`, but then if you're creating the `dc:*` elements in another template you'd have to repeat the `xmlns:dc` there as well.  Overall, I find it easier to put all the declarations at the root unless you have specific reasons not to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although I tried your approach by adding all the namespace declarations in the root, still it gives me the following error when trying to perform the transformation.
**Namespace for prefix 'dc' has not been declared**

Comment: @PawanSaha is it complaining about the stylesheet or about the input XML document?  Do you maybe have `<dc:something>` elements in the _input_ without an `xmlns:dc` declaration?

Answer (score 0):

There's really no special secret to projecting namespaces and aliases into output documents - as with other xml documents, declare them in the root element, and then use the aliases. AFAIK the `schemaLocation` will need to be manually mapped onto the root element as an attribute. Here's a basic skeleton template (note that I've skipped most of the elements)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.0" 
                xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1" 
                xmlns:prl="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/prl/2.0" 
                xmlns:mgh="http://comp.com/prismPlus-XSD">

    <xsl:template match="/Heard">
    <mgh:message> <!--OR of course <msh xmlns="...">-->
       <xsl:attribute name="schemaLocation" 
                      namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      >http://comp.com/prismPlus-XSD HeardsContent.xsd</xsl:attribute>
      <mgh:article>
        <mgh:head>
          <dc:identifier>
            <xsl:value-of select="some/path/to/value"></xsl:value-of>
          </dc:identifier>
          <prism:keyword>
            <xsl:value-of select="Topic"></xsl:value-of>
          </prism:keyword>
        </mgh:head>
        <mgh:contentFeatureBody>
          <body> <!--Note, global namespace so no alias or xmlns-->
            <xsl:value-of select="TextBody"></xsl:value-of>
          </body>
        </mgh:contentFeatureBody>
      </mgh:article>
    </mgh:message>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the following output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mgh:message xsi:schemaLocation="http://comp.com/prismPlus-XSD HeardsContent.xsd" 
             xmlns:mgh="http://comp.com/prismPlus-XSD" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.0" 
             xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1" 
             xmlns:prl="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/prl/2.0">
  <mgh:article>
    <mgh:head>
      <dc:identifier></dc:identifier>
      <prism:keyword>XX,YY,ZZ</prism:keyword>
    </mgh:head>
    <mgh:contentFeatureBody>
      <body>xxxxxxxxx</body>
    </mgh:contentFeatureBody>
  </mgh:article>
</mgh:message>
```